# reference for proof a theorem in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a group and $K$ be a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ ($|G:K|=2$). Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then H is subgroup of K or $|K:K \cap H|=2$. I want a reference for see the proof of this theorem.

Comment: "Reference"? Why don't you prove it yourself? For example, show that $\;K\cap H\lhd K\;$ and use some isomorphism theorem...

Comment: You can apply one of the isomorphism theorems here after observing that $G = HK$ when $H$ is not a subgroup of $K$.